# How to post values for each image with jquery each method?

Tags: jquery, post, each

I've html code:

```
<div>
  <span class="image" id="img-1"></span>
  <span id="src-1">img-src-1</span>
  <span id="cmd-1">img-cmd-1</span>
  <span id="h1-1">img-h1-1</span>
  <span id="h2-1">img-h2-1>
</div>

<div>
  <span class="image" id="img-2"></span>
  <span id="src-2">img-src-2</span>
  <span id="cmd-2">img-cmd-2</span>
  <span id="h1-2">img-h1-2</span>
  <span id="h2-2">img-h2-2>
</div>
```

and others incrementing divs like img-3, img-4, img-5 ..... with related values

this is my javascript:

```
$('.image').each(function() {
  $.post("../../includes/processes/show-images.php", {
    width : $(this).parent().width(),
    img_src : $(this).next().text(),
    cmd : $(this).next().next().text(),
    h1 : $(this).next().next().next().text(),
    h2 : $(this).next().next().next().next().text()
  },
  function(response){
    $(this).parent().html(response);
  });
});
return false;
```

I want post for each ".image" element its values and return in ".image".parent() the response, but my code doesn't work. :-(

Can somebody help me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` keyword within the context of the `$.post` 's callback function doesn't refer to the clicked element, cache the object:

```
$('.image').each(function() {
   var $this = $(this);
   $.post("../../includes/processes/show-images.php", {
    // ...
   }, function(response){
       $this.parent().html(response);
   });
});
```

You can also use `.siblings()` and `.eq()` methods instead of calling `.next()` methods several times:

```
$('.image').each(function() {
      var $this = $(this),
          $siblings = $this.siblings();
      $.post("../../includes/processes/show-images.php", {
          width   :  $this.parent().width(),
          img_src :  $siblings.eq(0).text(),
          cmd     :  $siblings.eq(1).text(),
          // ...
       }, function(response){
           $this.parent().html(response);
       });
});
```